# Google Script says: You have been creating or deleting too many calendars or calendar events in a short time. Please try again later

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I am getting this extremely frustrating error. I am in no way creating or deleting too many calendars - at most I've created about 20 and my script is trying to create just one!

I've narrowed down the problem to `event.addGuests()`. When I remove this line, the event gets added. When I keep it, this is where Google reports the error to be.

I've tried adding

```
Utilities.sleep(5000);
```

before `event.addGuest()` to see if slowing the script down would work, but this doesn't work either.

Here is the whole script. Note, there is only one item in the spreadsheet now

```
var ACCEPTED = "ACCEPTED";
var PUBLISHED = "PUBLISHED"
var NOT_PUBLISHED = "NOT_PUBLISHED";


function createCalendarEventsFromSheets(){
  // Get Calendar Info
  var calId = "privatecalendar@group.calendar.google.com";// use default claendar for tests
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);

  // Get Google Sheet Info
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('privatespreadhseet');
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var rows = range.getValues();
  Logger.log("Rows found: " + rows.length);
  // Iterate through Google Sheets rows and create events
  for (i = 1; i < rows.length; i++){
    var row  = rows[i];
    // Gather variables for row
    var eventTitle = row[1];
    var date       = new Date(row[2]);
    var location   = row[3];
    var shiftStart = row[4];
    var shiftEnd   = row[5];
    var eventStart = row[6];
    var eventEnd   = row[7];
    var numberOfKeys = row[8];
    var role       = row[9];
    var notes      = row[10];
    var accepted   = row[13];
    var alreadyPublished = row[14]

    // If event has been accepted and wasn't published yet, create event
    Logger.log("accepted: " + accepted + ", alreadyPublished " + alreadyPublished);

    if (accepted == ACCEPTED && alreadyPublished != PUBLISHED){
      Logger.log("**** TRUE ****");
      // Set up calendar event
      var cal_start = new Date(date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), shiftStart.getHours(), shiftStart.getMinutes());
      Logger.log("cal_start: " + cal_start);
      var cal_end = new Date(date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), shiftEnd.getHours(), shiftEnd.getMinutes());
      Logger.log("cal_end: " + cal_end);

      var description = "Keys Required: " + numberOfKeys + "\n\nRole: " + role + "\n\nEvent Start Time: " + eventStart.getHours() + ":" + eventStart.getMinutes() + ", Event End Time: " + eventEnd.getHours() + ":" + eventEnd.getMinutes() + "\n\nNotes:\n" + notes;

      // CREATE EVENT
      var event = cal.createEvent(eventTitle, cal_start, cal_end);

      event.setDescription(description);
      event.setLocation(location);
      //Utilities.sleep(5000); // I've tried this, to no avail
      event.addGuest("rap@gmail.com"); //error message details point to here
      event.addGuest('e.leg@gmail.com');
      event.addGuest('ba@hotmail.com');
      event.addGuest('r@hotmail.com');
      event.addGuest('js@gmail.com');
      event.addGuest('w@gmail.com');
      event.addGuest('no.abe@gmail.com');
      event.addGuest('esth@gmail.com');
      event.addGuest('carolin@gmail.com');
      event.addGuest('kalan@gmail.com');
      event.addGuest('bob@gmail.com');
      event.addGuest('rob@gmail.com');

      sheet.getRange(i+1, 15).setValue(PUBLISHED);
      Logger.log("Event created, starting at: " + event.getStartTime());

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems like this issue is something of an anomaly.  All the examples I've seen online ended up having workarounds, with no one finding a true solution.  They also all seemed to have different causes.  One thing I would suggest is adding a sleep in between every .addGuest call, just to see if maybe adding guests in rapid succession could be the issue.  Have you narrowed it down to the very first .addGuest call throwing the error? Or just that somewhere in there is the issue

Comment: What doesn't make sense to me is the fact that addGuest function is the cause of that error. Whereas, according to [this](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en), I would've expected to see a "Sending too many invitations or emails to external guests" instead. Have you tried adding a 1 second wait between adding guests? Not a very elegant method, I know. But just wondering if that might fix the problem.

Comment: Suggestion :
        `// CREATE EVENT
              var event = cal.createEvent(eventTitle, cal_start, cal_end);
              var ID = event.getId();
              event.setDescription(description);
              event.setLocation(location);
              cal.getEventSeriesById(ID).addGuest(("rap@gmail.com");
              cal.getEventSeriesById(ID).addGuest('e.leg@gmail.com');
              cal.getEventSeriesById(ID).addGuest('ba@hotmail.com');
              ...`
I've had that kind of issue too in the past and calling the same event for every guest solved the issue... so I suggest to try.

Comment: @pointNclick As soon as I remove `addGuest()` it works. It only blocks me when I use `addGuest`

Comment: @Sergeinsas I will try that next time I need to add some events... I ended up creating the events with the script and manually copying in the guest list to each. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: @JonathanSeed I tried adding a sleep before and between every `addGuest` call. Didn't work